# Python Robotparser Timeout equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x, robots.txt

Is there a way in Python 3.3.0 to set the timeout of the robotparser.read() function?
(such as in the urllib.request urlopen)

The default timeout of 60 seconds is a bit drastic.

(I'm self-teaching myself into Python.)

[Python 3.3.0 - robotparser](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.robotparser.html?highlight=robotparser#urllib.robotparser.RobotFileParser.read)

[Python 3.3.0 - urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you'd have to either set the global default timout with [`socket.setdefaulttimeout()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout), or subclass the `RobotFileParser` class to add a custom timeout:

```
from urllib.robotparser import RobotFileParser
import urllib.request

class TimoutRobotFileParser(RobotFileParser):
    def __init__(self, url='', timeout=60):
        super().__init__(url)
        self.timeout = timeout

    def read(self):
        """Reads the robots.txt URL and feeds it to the parser."""
        try:
            f = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url, timeout=self.timeout)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            if err.code in (401, 403):
                self.disallow_all = True
            elif err.code >= 400:
                self.allow_all = True
        else:
            raw = f.read()
            self.parse(raw.decode("utf-8").splitlines())
```